# the statement "An exception can be thrown by throw keyword explicitly" is true or not?

Tags: java

below is a multiple choice question, I think (A) and (D) both right,but standard answer is (D)

> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> (A) An exception can be thrown by throw keyword explicitly.
>
> (B) An RuntimeException must be caught explicitly.
>
> (C) An uncaught NullPointerException will cause a compilation error.
>
> (D) An overriding method can throw a different exception from its overriden method.

The statement of (A) is wrong ? I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have this from, or from where do you know it is supposed to be "D"? "D" would be too general to accept that as a correct answer in my point of view.

Comment: @WynWu Only A is definitely right. Statement D is ambiguous.

Comment: @Tom the question from interview i attend, and the answer is provided by interviewer.

Comment: If only D should be right then it could be that in answer A not the `throw` keyword but the `throws` keyword is meant which makes the answer indeed wrong.

Comment: *(A) An exception can be thrown by throw keyword explicitly.* can be ? i would say must be. What is the other way?

Comment: Maybe this is a typographical error, obviously (A) is correct unless replacing throw with throws

Comment: @Antoniossss e.g. `((String) null).length()`, `(new String[0])[1]`, `1 / 0`: these throw an exception without explicit throw.

Comment: D is true? That is change is signature.

Comment: Those questions are kind of dull as they are ambigous and everyone can have different answer which will be valid in context of what that someone understands that question is about.

Comment: For example - when I read A i thought of "how you can intentionally throw given exception?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw` keyword allows an exception inside of a function and the `throws` keyword is used in the throw statement of the method signature to state what exceptions might thrown by the function. 
EX:

```
public static void brokenFunc() throws Exception {
    throw new  Exception();
}
```

Now an overriden method cannot throw an exception that is broader than the exception of the super method. The only time this is an exception (did you see what I did there?) is when it's a runtime exception because they are unchecked exception. This would mean that option A is correct.

Making edit to address how the answer could be D.

1. The interview made a mistake and meant throws not throw
2. D refers to unchecked exceptions
3. D refers to overloaded method not overriding method
4. D means extending exceptions as different exceptions

If you google search answer A, you'll find a large amount of sources that states an exception can be thrown by throw keyword explicitly. There is not way to say that D is the standard question. No version of Java supports different exceptions from overridden methods because all checked exceptions will extend the exception from the super method. Extending exceptions has a `is a` relationship to the super exception so it is not "different". Runtime exceptions are not referred to as exceptions only because that does not make sense. A runtime exception is an exception but an exception is not a runtime exception in java so that should not be the case used in this question. This makes it seem like the interview was wrong to some degree and did not phrase the question correctly. I personally would not want to work there.